# How to use get; set; with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a class in C# that I would like to pull specific fields from a table using LINQ so I don't have to write code for every field I need.

I've looked around but I cannot find or learn how to do this.

This is what I have so far

```
    public class OrderInfo
    {
        private string shipmentId { get; set; }

        public string ShipmentId
        {
            get { return shipmentId; }
            set { ShipmentId = value; }
        }

        public void GetInfo()
        {
            OrderInfo oi = new OrderInfo()

            var _query = from p in shipmentHeader.SHIPMENT_HEADERs
                         where p.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM == 123
                         select new
                         {
                             oi.ShipmentId = p.SHIPMENT_ID
                         };
        }
    }
```

Once I do this, then my next question will be how do you call this from you main program.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have `GetInfo` return `IQueryable<OrderInfo>` rather than `void`. Then have the **calling code** request the specific column it wants.

Comment: Would you be kind and show me some code around how this will be done?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of @jorame suggestion,

```
    static public IQueryable<OrderInfo> QueryByShipmentNumber( int shipmentNum)
    {
        var _query = from p in shipmentHeader.SHIPMENT_HEADERs
                     where p.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM == shipmentNum
                     select new OrderInfo(p)
        return _query;
    }
```

Notice we are making this static. Also I am assuming there is a way to create an OrderInfo from a shipment header. Then for the second part,

```
 from oi in OrderInfo.QueryByShipmentNumber( 123) select oi.ShipmentId
```

This is not totally complete but hopefully gives you the idea.